# What complexity class is O(N^N)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I was looking at a naive solution[0] to the N-Queens problem that had worst case performance of O(N^N) and I am curious if there is a name for that complexity class, or is it just lumped into "factorial"?

[0] http://www.cs.ucc.ie/~dgb/courses/toc/handout25.pdf

Comment: By the Stirling formula, n!~√2πn (n/e)^n, so that the power and factorial aren't so different. (Taking the logarithms, you get O(n log(n)) for both.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but the class is called DTIME(n<sup>n</sup>) (technically you need a decision problem, e.g., given k and n, are there at least k distinct n-Queens solutions?). It doesn't have a fancy name because it's just not that interesting to complexity theorists. It's contained in [EXPTIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME), which is the union of DTIME(2<sup>p(n)</sup>) for all polynomials p(n). The naive n-Queens algorithm actually witnesses membership in the subclass [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) because it uses only O(n) lg(n)-bit words of storage, i.e., a polynomial number of bits. It is widely hypothesized that PSPACE is a strict subclass of EXPTIME.

Comment: Interesting...  so since it is included in that EXPTIME there must be a polynomial p(n) such that 2^p(n) roughly equals n^n, correct?

Comment: @racarate Not a polynomial, but sandwiched between them: n lg n, which is omega(n) and o(n^1.000001).

Answer (score -4):

These classes are called `Non Polynomial(NP)` time. As their running time is not of the form of a polynomial of n, where n is the input size.

Some other example of NP time complexity can be `O(2^N), O(N^log(N))`
Wile Polynomial time algorithms' time can be `O(P(N))`
where `P(N)` is a polynomial of N.

for more information read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)

Comment: I know that, but there is a huge difference in running time between exponential and factorial functions.  For instance, the dynamic programming algorithm for TSP takes it down from factorial time into exponential time which is a big deal.

Comment: I see what you are saying though, perhaps I used the term "complexity class" too loosely -- what I am really looking for is the street name.

Comment: Well, there are P and NP classes in theory, and clearly O(N^N) problem is NP

Comment: Big confusion: NP is the class of non-deterministic polynomial algorithms (i.e. which can find a solution quickly "by chance"). It is not the class of non-polynomial algorithms. There is no doubt about polynomial != non-polynomial.